# How can I send data from json to the html page in node.js?

Tags: node.js, json

I am trying to write a code for creating school website.I can control the passwords in terms of matching but I wanna send them to the true page when passwords match and for example I wanna send data which is coming from json and display the html page but no matter how hard I tried,I couldn't.If somebody help me I would be appreciate it.

EDIT:If anybody at least know how can I display the html page after maching the password I would be appreciate it.I wrote a code for that but it did not work.I am gonna show that part in the code.

Here is the code:

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url');

var users = [
               { "username":"admn", "password": "admn", "role": "admin" },
               { "username":"teachr", "password": "teachr", "role": "teacher" },
               { "username":"studnt", "password": "studnt", "role": "student" }
            ]

var data = [
              { "Projectname":"sdfsf", "projectteacher": "sdfsd", "thestudentthatgottheproject": "tsdf" },
              { "Projectname":"sdfsf", "projectteacher": "sdfsd", "thestudentthatgottheproject": "tsdf" },
              { "Projectname":"sdfsf", "projectteacher": "sdfsd", "thestudentthatgottheproject": "tsdf" }
           ]
function handle_incoming_request(req, res) {
    console.log("INCOMING REQUEST: " + req.method + " " + req.url);
    req.parsed_url = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var core_url = req.parsed_url.pathname;
    if (core_url == '/anasayfa.html') {
       res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type" : "text/html" });
       res.end('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>mainpage</title></head><body><form action="http://localhost:8080/ucheck.html" method="get"><input type="text" name="username"><input type="password" name="password"><input type="submit" value="sdfs"></form></body></html>');
    }
    else if (core_url == '/ur_check.html') {
      var getp = req.parsed_url.query;
      console.log(getp.username + " " + getp.password);
      for(i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
        if( (users[i].username == getp.username) && (users[i].password == getp.password)){
           switch ( users[i].role ){
              case "admin"        :     //These parts are not working.
              function req(request,response)
              {
                response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type" : "text/html" });
                fs.readFile('./admin.html',null,function(error,data){
                  if(error)
                  {
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write('File not found.')
                  }
                  else{
                    response.write(data);
                  }
                  });response.end();
              };break;
              case "student"      :
              function req(request,response)
              {
                response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type" : "text/html" });
                fs.readFile('./student.html',null,function(error,data){
                  if(error)
                  {
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write('File not found.')
                  }
                  else{
                    response.write(data);
                  }
                  });response.end();
              }; break;
              case "teacher"   :
              function req(request,response)
              {
                response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type" : "text/html" });
                fs.readFile('./teacher.html',null,function(error,data){
                  if(error)
                  {
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write('File not found.')
                  }
                  else{
                    response.write(data);
                  }
                  });response.end();
              }; break;
           }
            res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type" : "application/json" });
            res.end(JSON.stringify( { result: "FOUND", username: users[i].username, password: users[i].password, role: users[i].role }) + "\n");

            return;
          }
        }
      res.writeHead(404, { "Content-Type" : "application/json" });
      res.end(JSON.stringify({ result: "NOT FOUND", message: "USERNAME OR PASSWORD INVALID" }) + "\n");
   }
   else {
     res.writeHead(404, { "Content-Type" : "application/json" });
     res.end(JSON.stringify({ error: "NOT SUPPORTED YET", message: "REQUESTED PAGE DOES NOT EXIST" }) + "\n");
  }
var s = http.createServer(handle_incoming_request);
s.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem requires a backend. If you know `javascript` I would suggest you to  use `express js`.

Comment: I am not good at java script.If you know  the solution and help me to fix this I would be appreciate it.I am really stuck.@altair00